# Safari renders wrong colors when using blur filter

Tags: jquery, html, svg, safari, svg-filters

I try to apply a blur filter to a svg elment, but it seems that Safari can't render the colors right. Here is an example of my problem:

```
<svg height="110" width="110">
    <defs>
          <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
               <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15" />
          </filter>
    </defs>
        <rect width="90" height="90"  stroke-width="3" fill="#ff4300" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6gZ8t/1/

Safari:

[image: This is Safari]

Chrome:

[image: This is Chrome]

The color is right in every brwoser expet Safari, where it is much brighter...Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Safari's default color interpolation (linearRGB) seems to be broken in recent updates. If you switch to sRGB across the board in your filters, you will get more correct results (although they'll all be gamma corrected).

```
<filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
```

Comment: You can also apply it to the gaussian filter only: `<filter ...><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"/></filter>`. Let's hope however for the WebKit team to fix this soon.