# SVG gaussian blur in Safari unexpectedly lightens image

Tags: svg, safari, gaussian, svg-filters

Using svg guassian blur filter to perform cross browser image blurring. Overall, it works really well except in the case of Safari.

In desktop Safari, the image is blurred but it is also lightened. This doesn't happen in any other browser (literally tested in Firefox, Chrome, IE9-11, and mobile Safari in iOS 7).

Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the live svg filter and a linked screenshot from what Safari is seeing, http://jsfiddle.net/vtDYg/3/

Here also is the svg code current in use:

```
<svg class="sg-blur-2">
  <defs>
    <filter id="sg-blur-2">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://fillmurray.com/300/100" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#sg-blur-2)"></image>
</svg>
```

Here's what desktop Safari is seeing:
[image]

I thought the color space of the jpeg in question might be an issue, so I specified the 'color-profile' attribute to both 'sRGB', 'RGB', and 'rgb' but that had no effect.

Comment: Does specifying different values for color-interpolation-filters (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ColorInterpolationFiltersProperty) make any difference to Safari? If not then it may be operating in the wrong colour space.

Comment: @RobertLongson Please add that as an answer so I can accept it, upvote it, and gold plate it. That worked EXACTLY.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safari renders wrong colors when using blur filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615663/safari-renders-wrong-colors-when-using-blur-filter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer, recommended by @RobertLongson in the first comment, requires the attribute 'color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"' to the feGaussianBlur filter.

http://jsfiddle.net/vtDYg/6/

```
<svg class="sg-blur-2">
  <defs>
    <filter id="sg-blur-2">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"></feGaussianBlur>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://fillmurray.com/300/100" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#sg-blur-2)"></image>
</svg>
```

To the best of my knowledge, the svg spec indicates that feGaussianBlur filter should use the linearRGB color space by default. All browsers *except* Safari 7 seem to do this incorrectly and default to sRGB. Oddly, mobile Safari also defaults to sRGB.

Answer (score 9):

It seems like you can correct or at least improve things by setting color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" on the filter.

feGaussianBlur should work in the linearRGB colour space with premultiplied RGBA by default with color-interpolation-filters allowing it to be switched to sRGB. That is certainly the case with Firefox since I wrote the code to do that there.

Comment: I'm curious about this. After I read the part of the spec you referenced, it occurred to me that superficially it seems that every browser *except* desktop Safari 7 is defaulting to sRGB rather than linearRGB. I don't have a deep understanding of this.

Comment: I do not believe that is true. Safari's linearRGB implementation is *broken* LinearRGB is correctly supported as the default for SVG filters in other browsers.

Comment: There is definitely something wrong there. I filed a [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136418).

Comment: @RobertLongson - unfortunately I'm still seeing the lightening in Safari, here's a sample page: https://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/GJPjjQ Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @jbenjohnson Safari is open source, download it and fix the bug that David Bonnet raised, or pay someone else to do so.