# Safari svg gaussian blur (feGaussianBlur) wont render stdDeviation less than 1?

Tags: svg, safari, webkit, svg-filters

A complex logo I'm rendering shows artifacts between the different shapes. 
These are not gaps in the artwork, but aliasing artifacts.

I found a good solution for removing these artifacts, being to mask the object and apply a very slight gaussian blur (feGaussianBlur) with a low  stdDeviation value (0.125).

Chrome, firefox and even IE display it well. Desktop Safari (8.0) however seems to always treat the blur as if the value was at least 1px (or so it seems to be) making it too blurry to be an acceptable representation of the logo.

Is there a way to make safari support a value between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that setting the stdDeviation of the blur to 0 had the desired effect across all browsers. Safari needed the color-interpolation-filters set to "sRGB" (other browsers default to it: [SVG gaussian blur in Safari unexpectedly lightens image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295043/svg-gaussian-blur-in-safari-unexpectedly-lightens-image)).

Here's where I wound up, it seems to work consistently, but we're going to use a png for now and compensate for hi DPI devices:

```
    <filter id="blur" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" />
   </filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak blurs using the `<feComponentTransfer>` and `feFuncA>`elements.The following will tighten up your blur but probably keep your artifacts hidden if not, play with the tableValues array.

> ```
> <feComponentTransfer >
>    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0 0.5 1"/>
> </feComponentTransfer>
> ```